# How should stucco/waterproofing be addressed around balcony sides at building corners?

Tags: waterproofing, stucco, transition, balcony

I'm waterproofing my new ADU build and I'm stumped at the stucco/balcony transition on the outer edges, which happens to be the corners of the building. The siding will be 3 coat stucco over 0.4" rain-screen (~1.3" total siding thickness). I'll have fascia attached to the perimeter of the balcony, on top of which I'll put my drip edge, waterproofing membrane on the entire deck, then metal flashing to wall, then WRB over that up the wall.

What is the best way to address the outer sides of this balcony/wall corner transition? With all the factors at play (flashing to wall above deck, weep-screed on wall extending to building corners, 0.4" rain-screen under the stucco, fascia placement (I could simply mount right to pressure treated sides or fur out), I'm at a loss. The plans do not have this detail unfortunately.

I'm looking for simple, clean aesthetics and the best waterproofing possible. Anyone have suggestions and/or pictures of how this is supposed to look? Keep in mind, the framing might not be correct but this is what the framers gave me to work with.

[image: front]

[image: left side]

[image: left side]

[image: right side]

[image: right side]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the corners will get stucco, wrap those corners with the WRB that you've used over the rest of the sheathing. As you work upwards from the bottom with the rain-screen, cover those corners with a strip of it. I would try to have it be a strip that was contiguous with a section just below. This will give you the needed 2 WRB layers.

On the deck perimeter I would forego the fascia and cut that floating plywood edge back, flush with the deck joists. This would put your 4 x 4 posts at the corners and facilitate clean railing picket attachment to the joists.

At the deck/wall transition, I would pitch your metal flashing a bit, from the center towards outboard, and wrap the flashing over the deck edge a bit. This will help the water that weeps from the stucco to be shed away from the deck.